# Matlab: Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
labs = 1:1334;

for i = 1:1334
    labs(i) = num2str(i,'%06.f');
end
```

I want to put "000001" "000002" etc as strings into the "labs" array. However, it says each side has a different number of elements. Why don't they both only have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that `labs` is defined as a `double` array by default, meaning that its elements are expected to be numeric. In the `for` loop, you're trying to assign `string` values (using the `num2str` function) to the `labs` array which is of the class `double`. A workaround would be to define `labs` as a `cell` array, which can store `string` values.

```
N = 1334;
labs = cell(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    labs{i} = num2str(i,'%06.f');
end
```

The only caveat is that `labs` is now a `cell` array, which requires a different syntax than regular `double` arrays to index its elements.